How to emulate ARM Raspberry Pi OS on an Intel desktop computer running Ubuntu?
I am co-maintainer of an eye strain prevention app (Safe Eyes), and want to test it in Raspberry Pi OS before release.
I don't have a Raspberry Pi, so I cannot test how the app works in the new Wayland based desktop environment.
Therefore, I want to emulate it within Ubuntu (using something like Virtualbox, not ARM).
How to emulate ARM64 version of Raspberry Pi OS in AMD64 version of Ubuntu 24.04?
I have heard of QEMU, but I don't know how to set it up to run an ARM OS on an Intel desktop computer. I am looking for a step-by-step guide.

Please note that the question is how to set up the infrastructure to run an ARM OS within Ubuntu. The question is not about how to do X in Raspberry Pi OS. Therefore it is on-topic on this site.
